# List of all IBM motherboard models with a certain socket?

Tags: ibm, hardware

I just got a really good deal on two Intel Quad Core Xeon L5420 processors and I have access to other deals on bare IBM servers (case+motherboard, no processor/ram/hdd). How can I easily find out what server or motherboard models will be compatible with this processor? I am ideally looking for a dual-processor motherboard and I see that it is socket LGA771.

So I guess the underlying question is, how can I find **what IBM motherboards (and servers) have dual socket LGA 771?**

Comment: Do you really mean *actual* branded IBM hardware? Or do you just mean X86?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel Xeon L5420 is known on IBM systems as 44E5133.

[This compatibility matrix](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/info/x86servers/serverproven/compat/us/xseries/upgrades/procmatrix4.html) indicates that at least ibm x3650 supports this processor (as it is provided w/ model 7979)

Ibm says that it has been tested, and so it works. But maybe other server models with similar processors could accept the L5420.